# Out of memory exception on WAS 6.1 and EJB 2.1

Tags: out-of-memory, websphere-6.1, ejb-2.x, struts-1

My application is going out of memory and getting internal server error for some time and after that it is automatically recovered and the application is running fine.

My application is hosted on WAS 6.1 and using Struts 1.1 and EJB 2.1.
Here are the application server logs for the error. Could you please help me on this issue please.

```
[7/14/15 12:58:06:238 BST] 00000038 HttpConnectio E   Unable to read and handle request: null
[7/14/15 12:58:19:793 BST] 00000464 DiscoveryServ W   DCSV1115W: DCS Stack DefaultCoreGroup at Member gal72050Cell\gal72050\fleetmanagement_1: Member gal72050Cell\gal72050\cid_1 connection  was closed. Member will  be removed from view. DCS connection status is Discovery|Ptp, transmitter closed.
[7/14/15 12:58:19:808 BST] 00000468 LTPAServerObj W   SECJ0371W: Validation of the LTPA token failed because the token expired with the following info: Token expiration Date: Tue Jul 14 10:53:38 BST 2015, current Date: Tue Jul 14 12:58:19 BST 2015.
[7/14/15 12:58:19:816 BST] 00000467 LTPAServerObj W   SECJ0371W: Validation of the LTPA token failed because the token expired with the following info: Token expiration Date: Tue Jul 14 12:25:18 BST 2015, current Date: Tue Jul 14 12:58:19 BST 2015.
[7/14/15 12:58:12:539 BST] 0000043c ExceptionUtil E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "getWorkshop" on bean "BeanId(fleetmanagement_FMS#VUTEJB.jar#WorkshopService, null)". Exception data: <malformed parameter>
[7/14/15 12:58:19:780 BST] 00000014 ApplicationMo W   DCSV0004W: DCS Stack DefaultCoreGroup at Member gal72050Cell\gal72050\fleetmanagement_1: Did not receive adequate CPU time slice. Last known CPU usage time at 12:53:52:795 BST. Inactivity duration was 175 seconds. 
[7/14/15 12:58:19:189 BST] 00000448 ExceptionUtil E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "doSearch" on bean "BeanId(fleetmanagement_FMS#VUTEJB.jar#AtoService, null)". Exception data: <malformed parameter>
[7/14/15 12:58:19:189 BST] 0000043b ExceptionUtil E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "issueSearch" on bean "BeanId(fleetmanagement_FMS#VUTEJB.jar#IssueManagementService, null)". Exception data: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.im.model.jdbc.OracleIssueDao.createIssueDto(OracleIssueDao.java:718)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.im.model.jdbc.OracleIssueDao.createIssueSearchResultDto(OracleIssueDao.java:768)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.im.model.jdbc.OracleIssueDao.issueSearch(OracleIssueDao.java:506)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.vut.service.IssueManagementServiceBean.issueSearch(IssueManagementServiceBean.java:533)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.vut.service.EJSLocalStatelessIssueManagementService_0f9a1a53.issueSearch(Unknown Source)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.im.actions.IssueSearchAction.execute(IssueSearchAction.java:40)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:989)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:930)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at com.ford.jlr.tag.crumb.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ford.jlr.tag.table.ExportFilter.doFilter(ExportFilter.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ford.jlr.tag.table.CustomizeViewFilter.doFilter(CustomizeViewFilter.java:73)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:674)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:498)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:464)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:744)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1455)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:383)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1469)

[7/14/15 12:58:10:251 BST] 0000044a ExceptionUtil E   CNTR0020E: EJB threw an unexpected (non-declared) exception during invocation of method "getCategoriesCollection" on bean "BeanId(fleetmanagement_FMS#VUTEJB.jar#VehicleSearchService, null)". Exception data: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1461)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.setSessionFields(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:890)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.<init>(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:185)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:352)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:297)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:157)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:94)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper$1.run(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:868)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:246)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:863)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.getPooledConnection(WSRdbDataSource.java:1185)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1055)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:1811)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1543)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2215)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:896)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:596)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:431)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:400)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.vut.model.JdbcHelper.getConnection(JdbcHelper.java:83)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.vut.model.JdbcHelper.doSelect(JdbcHelper.java:304)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.vut.model.jdbc.OracleVehicleSearchDao.getCategoriesCollection(OracleVehicleSearchDao.java:295)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.vut.service.VehicleSearchServiceBean.getCategoriesCollection(VehicleSearchServiceBean.java:547)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.vut.service.EJSLocalStatelessVehicleSearchService_0b6828ec.getCategoriesCollection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.fms.data.search.SearchDataManager.getCategories(SearchDataManager.java:51)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.vut.forms.VehicleSearchForm.getAllCategories(VehicleSearchForm.java:439)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.vut.actions.search.FleetSearchAjaxAction.getCategoriesList(FleetSearchAjaxAction.java:148)
    at com.ford.jlr.pd.vut.actions.search.FleetSearchAjaxAction.attachChoices(FleetSearchAjaxAction.java:72)
    at com.ford.jlr.struts.AjaxDependentListAction.execute(AjaxDependentListAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:989)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:930)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at com.ford.jlr.tag.crumb.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ford.jlr.tag.table.ExportFilter.doFilter(ExportFilter.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ford.jlr.tag.table.CustomizeViewFilter.doFilter(CustomizeViewFilter.java:73)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:766)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:674)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:498)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:464)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:744)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1455)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:383)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:263)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1469)
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` suggests that you run out of memory in the application server. For quick workaround you can increase max heap size in the application server, but in general you should enable verbose gc and generate heap dumps. Then analyze the dump looking for memory leaks and learning what is taking space in the heap.

You can use tools from [IBM Support Assistant](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/isa/) (available for free) :

- Garbage Collection and Memory Visualizer
- IBM HeapAnalyzer